# How to get continuos value changes from input slider element?

Tags: javascript, events, web-audio-api

I am fooling aroung with the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). Right now I am trying to implement an input slider to control the frequency of an [Oscillator Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode).
When I "grab" the slider and move it, the frequency only changes in the moment I release the mousebutton, which results in a jump of the frequency. I would like to have the frequency changed in the moment I move the slider knob. Is that possible?

Here's my code:

```
var vco_freq_fader = document.getElementById("vco_freq");
var vco_freq_handler = function (event){
    osc.frequency.value = vco_freq_fader.value
};
vco_freq_fader.addEventListener('change', vco_freq_handler);
```

Comment: Use the `input` event on the slider not the `change` event.

Comment: Baam, as easy as that. Thanks. Gonna sit down and study event types! Why don't you write it as an answer?